# XNA Zune HD application won't exit gracefully

Tags: xna, zune, zune-hd

I have and built and deployed the application created by the new project template for the zune hd. The problem is whenever the application exits, the Zune reboots. This happens when remotely debugging from the PC or when running it right from the device. It happens both in debug mode and release. I've included the basic template code, but it's pretty generic. Anyone have any ideas?

```
public class DrawGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    private GraphicsDeviceManager m_graphics;
    private SpriteBatch m_spriteBatch;

    public DrawGame()
    {
        m_graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / 30.0);
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        m_spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    { }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            this.Exit();
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        m_spriteBatch.Begin();
        m_spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually by design and not you doing anything wrong.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254789.aspx) and [this blog](http://klucher.com/blog/zune-games-and-rebooting-devices/)

> The features that become disabled are the playback of DRM music and the ability to share content with other Zunes (outside of game information). The reason we do this is we want to keep the Zune secure while you’re writing your games on the device. The only way for us to re-enable these features is to restart the device

Comment: Wow. That's crazy, but I guess that's how it is. Thanks for the quick answer.